# Отправка POST запроса через планировщик

Tags: php, bash, post, curl, request

Добрый день. Есть HTML код

```html
<FORM ACTION="https://site.com/orderresult/orderresult.cfm" METHOD="POST">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Ordernumber" VALUE="1001-01">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Merchant_ID" VALUE="123">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Login" VALUE="lala">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Password" VALUE="pas">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Startyear" VALUE="2016">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Startmonth" VALUE="07">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Startday" VALUE="06">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Starthour" VALUE="00">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Startmin" VALUE="00">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Endyear" VALUE="2016">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Endmonth" VALUE="07">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Endday" VALUE="07">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Endhour" VALUE="00">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Endmin" VALUE="00">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Format" VALUE="3">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Language" VALUE="EN">
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="Submit" VALUE="Выполнить">
</FORM>
```

Как все эти параметры передавать POST запросом, но через планировщик? Именно так надо отслеживать статус заказа, но я не знаю, как отправлять именно POST запросы. Можно предложить реализацию на PHP или Bash.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$curl = curl_init(); //инициализация сеанса
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://site.com/orderresult/orderresult.cfm'); //урл сайта к которому обращаемся
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); //выводим заголовки
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); //передача данных методом POST
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //теперь curl вернет нам ответ, а не выведет
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, //тут переменные которые будут переданы методом POST
    array (
        "Ordernumber" => "1001-01",
        "Merchant_ID" => "123",
        "Login" => "lala",
        "Password" => "pas",
        "Startyear" => "2016",
        "Startmonth" => "07",
        "Startday" => "06",
        "Starthour" => "00",
        "Startmin" => "00",
        "Endyear" => "2016",
        "Endmonth" => "07",
        "Endday" => "07",
        "Endhour" => "00",
        "Endmin" => "00",
        "Format" => "3",
        "Language" => "EN"
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'MSIE 5'); //эта строчка как-бы говорит: "я не скрипт, я IE5" :)
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://ya.ru"); //а вдруг там проверяют наличие рефера
    $res = curl_exec($curl);
    //если ошибка то печатаем номер и сообщение
    if(!$res) {
        $error = curl_error($curl).'('.curl_errno($curl).')';
        echo $error;
    }
    else {
        //если результат содержит то что нам надо (проверяем регуляркой), а в данном случае это табличка с классом yaResultat, то выводим ее.
        if (preg_match("/\<table class\='yaResultat'(.+)\<\/table\>/isU", $res, $found)) {
            $content = $found[0];
            echo $content; //перед этим его конечно можно обработать всякими str_replace и т.д.
        }
        else {
            echo "<p>Неизвестная ошибка</p>"; //а если табличики с результатами нет, то печатать нечего и мы незнаем что делать :(
        }
    }
    curl_close($curl);`